# Apple in-app purchase. How to pull products that are available?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class where I suggest to a user to buy an in-app purchase. If the user clicks "buy" I am trying to initiate the purchasing process. But I am not sure where to get the product object that they are supposed to buy.

I have a method like this:

```
- (IBAction)makePurchase:(id)sender
{    
    [[PlanIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];
}
```

But where and how do I pull the product object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will definitely need to keep the product identifiers you have declared in iTunes Connect somewhere in your app (in a plist for example). From there on, implement the [SKProductsRequestDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsRequestDelegate/Reference/Reference.html) in the view controller that will present the available products. Some possible code snippets would be:

```
   // Put your product identifiers in an NSSet and perform the appropriate product request (i.e in viewDidLoad)
    NSSet *productIdentifiersForPurchase = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"product_id_1",@product_id_2",...nil];
    SKProductsRequest *productRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiersForPurchase];
    productRequest.delegate = self;
    [productRequest start];
```

And implement the delegate methods, as for example

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    if (!response.products) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Could not find matching products");
        return;
    }

    for (SKProduct *product in response.products) {
    // Do something with the retrieved products
   }
 }
```

Comment: thank you, is the productsIdentifiersForPurchase an array or just a string? I have just one item. So can I set it as a string with one id?

Comment: Also, where should I implement the delegate methods?

Comment: @Genadinik That depends on your app's design and flow. You can implement the protocol either in the view controller that will present the products and update the user interface (prices, names etc) when you get the response, or in a singleton and cache them for later use, or wherever suits you best. As far as the product identifiers are concerned you just need to define an `NSSet *productIdentifiersForPurchase = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"product_id_1",@product_id_2",...nil];`

Comment: @Genadinik sorry, I didn't realise your edit. If you have only one then things are easy `NSSet *productIdentifiersForPurchase = [NSSet setWithObject:@"product_id"];`

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the In-App Purchase store identifiers. You can either:

- Hardcode them in your app
- Load them from a file somewhere on the web

**You cannot load them using StoreKit framework, so you will have to look at iTunes Connect at some point.**

Using the store identifiers you can make a `SKProductsRequest`.

```
SKProductsRequest* request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:identifiers];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
```

You can then handle the response in a delegate object:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;

    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts)
    {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);

       [[PlanIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:skProduct];
    }
}
```

It is really hard to say what `PlanIAPHelper` does in this case, but the code that would pull the products is certainly not there.

The following links will help you on understanding how In-App Purchases work on iOS:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial
- https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Comment: I am ok hardcoding them into the app at first. I am already following the Ray Wanderlich tutorial. But I am a bit stuck on it because I am not sure how to set the product object which is sent in the [[PlanIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product]; call.

Comment: First you need to get the `SKProduct` objects before you can use that method. Try making a `SKProductsRequest` call.

Comment: do you mean like spassas suggested in his answer? I am currently trying to figure out the difference of passing a list of identifiers vs just one like in my case.

Comment: I've edited the code and inserted your `PlanIAPHelper`, practically this is very similar. The delegate can be the `UIViewController` that triggered the purchase.